# Shopping Cart Using Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a simple shopping cart using cookies/sessions. It just contains 4 items according to this code snippet,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 296px">



        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="164px" Width="107px" 
            SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem>Tyres</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Battery</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Front Glass</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Vanity Mirrors</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Username:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        EMail: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>



        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click" />



    </div>
    </form>
```

what I am trying is I am selecting all four items and on clicking the button, it will take me to the next page for entering prices and calculating prices and in the other page I will show the total with taxes. I am stuck on the second page as it just shows the First selection not the other three. Below is the code for second page:

```
public partial class confirm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["UserInfo"] != null)
        {
           // TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["userName"]);
            //TextBox2.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["email"]);
            Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["items"]);
            Label2.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["items"]);
            Label3.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["items"]);
            Label4.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["items"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas guys where I might be wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use cookies; you should use session variable: HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"] = whatever and var x = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"]

Comment: What does "MyValue" stand for?

Comment: Whatever variable name you want it to be: for the variable number of tires in the cart, you could choose CountTires and have  HttpContext.Current.Session["CountTires"] = 4;

Comment: can you give me any links where can I read about session variables in detail and clearly?

Comment: How u store listbox items to cookie? will u show code

Comment: I just did what I have shown :(

Comment: I recommend you check on youtube for "asp.net session" and watch a video tutorial to start. It's really very easy to start: key/value storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is a bad idea to store all the items that the user adds to the cart on cookies because the cookie have limitation on how many data you can store, and second the page carry all that data on every request and you make your page difficult to load.

If you try to save it on the session, then the user may lose whats on the cart when the session expire, and this can happens even at check out. For example, the user starts the check out, is stop for some minutes to do something, and then when its try to continue the session has expires.

The correct way is to keep the cart on a database, connected with the user cookie that have an expiration of six months at least.

### about your code

the bug on your code is that you use the same cookie name for all, that why you see only the first. See, this is the same and not changes on the lines.

```
Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["items"]
```

Comment: "the user may lose whats on the cart when the session expire": no, the session expires after 20 min of inactivity so that's not a valid argument. Session is the tool to use for his shopping cart. You might want to store the session in a database as opposed to InProc but that's a web.config setting. But overall, session state is the tool for the job.

Comment: @frenchie apparently you do not run a real online shop.

Comment: you're suggesting to store session-related data in a database but NOT in session state: that's bad advice. Still better to store in a database than in a cookie, of course. But, whatever: you probably run an online shop that doesn't get much traffic.

Comment: @frenchie I suggest that you can not save on session cart data because the cart must be the same and not change until payed. Why this is difficult to understand ? If you make cart and cart relative calculations on session, then the user, and statistically one user per day (at lease one) stay and check the cart for more than 20 minutes - with out do anything on the same site. For example is may stop to do some other job, or compare price with other stores etc... anyway do what ever you like.

Comment: The only reason for saving the shopping cart on a cookie is just to not force a user to sign in/signup and this scenariomust be temporarily. After a user decides to buy orders you should save that on the database for persistency/traceability/calculate shipping and ...

Comment: @QMaster Still do not need to store in cookie the cart - you store it on a temporary table on the server - and that ways you also keep statistics

Comment: @Aristos and how to trace users? you need save somthing to be able distinguish users. Don't you? So I think the best way to store shopping card when user not logged in is the cookie. Although you could encrypt cookie content if matter.

Comment: @QMaster You trace them with a cookie, unknown trace them.. think about and design... all ready implemented many times... and if the user get register you merge their data.

Comment: @Aristos can you please explain more? What is the relation key between temporary table and anonymous user? is the code you wrote in cookie and save in that temp table? so why you not just save shopping card in cookie? Or you mean another solutions?

Comment: @QMaster Users always have a cookie, a unique ID. Its did not matter if you know who is this user - so you have a simple table, with the cookie and the id of the product that add on cart plus the quantity, when he added, and anything else. So with this you hold the cart - of course we mean for a professional big e-shop, not an eshop that only s promote up to 10 products.

Comment: @Aristos You right, users have cookies. I just curious to know what is the reason to store temporary content to db when we can do it in the cookies. I think that is not matter in small or really big e-commerce website. If you have some reasons please describe.

Comment: @QMaster many reasons, among others, better user experience, faster page load, less bugs, more statistics, less exposed system... but need more work

Comment: @Aristos you mentioned some theoretical subjects. Any of them need to prove in the solution using a database over cookie in classified sections. For example, I don't assume DB transaction between user shopping process cause page load faster. completely reverse I believe using cookies will so faster because does not need interaction with the server. Applies to other subjects you mentioned: Better user experience, less bug, and so on

Comment: @QMaster here is a prove -> www.athineon.com

Comment: @Aristos That is your kindness to share real work for me. This is proof of your great work and abilities. but could not get the answer to my question. I need some special test and compare both solutions: Store temp shopping card in the database and the cookie.

Comment: @QMaster Is not answer to your question, because you do not ask for learn anything… you ask in a matter to teach to me… and no answer will ever satisfy you unless you agree with it. So please understand, I am not try to convince and prove to you anything. If you like to learn, make your tests by yourself as I have did mine. So please this is the end, of your meaningful questions that you already know the answers…

Comment: @Aristos I agree with you for ending this conversation, But I so amazed when you judge me! I just want to learn. We developed all our shopping websites by storing the shopping cart in the database. Just now we are in the middle of developing a shopping cart that doesn't need user login at first, So we take the cookie store as the best solution. When you suggest storing shopping cart in DB rather cookie I just want to know why and we need exact and strong reason to do that. anyway, I appreciate your kindness and companion.