# Where is a good place to put common business logic that should run on every view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project in which I need to check for and add a cookie, regardless of which view the user is currently on. I can place the code inside of the `_Layout` partial view within a code block, but I have doubts that's the conventional place for it. Where should it go?

Comment: @ekad Business logic in a view is a bad idea...

Comment: Why don't you make use of the session instead?

Comment: @Sam I'm storing an id in a cookie which maps to a shopping cart database entry for non-registered users.

Comment: So you could make use of the session for that. SessionID (HttpContext.Session.SessionID) would be a good option rather than creating your own ID for guest users.

Comment: @Sam SessionID expires too quickly. I need it to last at least 6 months.

Comment: That's true. But, keeping guest info for six months is not a good idea.

Comment: @Sam Hmm, I was actually just going based off this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10860767/1107110

Comment: Yes true. I didn't ask you to save the entire cart in session. I just asked to make use of the SessionID as a unique ID to track the user. This is an architectural decision that you have to make before going any further. Here are few tips. You need to decide where you'll store guest user information and cart details. Keeping in cookies is not safe. Because, the user might be using a public computer or shared one. Other users who use the same machine doesn't want to see previous user's information and it's not safe for the users as well.

Comment: E.g. if you save e-mail addresses and other contact details that could be seen by other users. So what I would do is save user details in a temporary table (call it TempCart) in the database based on the SessionID with e-mail address (and tel no or some unique value if possible) and save each item as it's being added to the cart. Then you could retrieve these information at checkout based on SessionID if session has not expired or if it's expired based on the e-mail address.

Comment: Once the payment has been made move the TempCart record to the actual cart or if the user didn't continue with the payment keep it few days (make a decision here how long you'll keep but keep it for lesser time otherwise the DB will grow exponentially). Hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @Sam, As I said, I can't use the session ID as it expires too quickly and I'd like to preserve a non-registered cart session for longer than the life span of the browser process. All I'll be storing in the cookie is a guid which represents the primary key of a cart table for non-registered users (essentially the temp cart you're suggesting). It contains a field for the expiry date and is pruned based on this value. When a user signs up, cart data is re-associated to the newly registered account, and the temp cart entry is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View is generally wrong place to put logic.

Action filter is one possible way to centralize the code and allow easy customization, especially for something that sound so close to behavior of [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) filter.

See [Action Filtering in ASP.Net MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for information.

```
public class MyCookieFilter : ActionFilterAttribute ...

[MyCookieFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // The action method logic.
}
```

Side note: when searching for documentation be carefull to distinguish MVC and WebAPI classes - many have similar names and similar behavior, but can cause some confusion when applied to wrong objects.